# Error opening camera with Xamarin.Forms and Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-camera, prism

**Code Behind**

```
    async Task BtnCameraEvento()
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            //Verifica se a camera está disponivel
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported || !CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Aviso", "Nenhuma camera detectada", "OK");

                return;
            }

            //tira a foto
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
            new StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = false,
                Directory = "Demo",
                Name = "foto"
            });

            //Verifica se foi tirado alguma foto
            if (file == null)
                return;

            //Adiciona a foto a lista de imagens
            _imageList.Add(file.Path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int x = 1;
        }
    }
```

The following error appears in the line "CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync":

> "Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project."

Comment: Did you set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project.` : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android-misc-setup

Comment: Can you show your AndroidManifest file?

Answer (score 2):

See particularly this section of the docs linked by sushihangover:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#android

Copied here in case link ever breaks:

> **Android**
>
> The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions are required, but the library will automatically add this for you. Additionally, if your users are running Marshmallow the Plugin will automatically prompt them for runtime permissions. You must add the Permission Plugin code into your Main or Base Activities:
>
> Add to Activity:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] 
permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.
        Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult
        (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

> **Android Current Activity Setup**
>
> This plugin uses the Current Activity Plugin to get access to the current Android Activity. Be sure to complete the full setup if a MainApplication.cs file was not automatically added to your application. Please fully read through the Current Activity Plugin Documentation. At an absolute minimum you must set the following in your Activity's OnCreate method:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

> It is highly recommended that you use a custom Application that are outlined in the Current Activity Plugin Documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md)
>
> **Android Misc Setup**
>
> By adding these permissions Google Play will automatically filter out devices without specific hardware. You can get around this by adding the following to your AssemblyInfo.cs file in your Android project:

```
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]
```

> **Android File Provider Setup**
>
> You must also add a few additional configuration files to adhere to the new strict mode:
>
> 1.) Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the <application> tags:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
      android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
      android:exported="false" 
      android:grantUriPermissions="true">

      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                 android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

> 2.) Add a new folder called xml into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called file_paths.xml. Make sure that this XML file has a Build Action of: AndroidResource.
>
> Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

> You can read more at: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html